# python subprocess call failing while same command line call works fine

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to replace a command line call by a Python script using subprocess:

```
path_to_executable = r'c:\UK\app\Debug\lll.exe'
x = subprocess.call([path_to_executable, args])
```

`args` is a string that looks like this:

```
-unemp Base -rate Base -scen_name Base -print_progress 0 -rate_date 1 -hpa Base -dealpath C:\data\ -nthread 4 -deallist C:\config\all.txt -outdir  c:\outdir\Base
```

The call is working when run from the command line, however failing with the same arguments in subprocess with the following error:

```
FileIOException(Unable to open directory C:/.../hist.csv)
```

(The csv file is present - but it's a file, not a directory.)

My questions: 
1. How could it be that it work through the command line but not subprocess?
2. Why might it be trying to open a csv file as a directory, when it's not doing the same thing on the command line?

Comment: Did you use forward slashes on the command line? Although python allows that, the windows commands you call typically do not.

Comment: Please share path_to_executable and args which cause this error.

Comment: In general, try to avoid specifying paths as full strings like that. Instead use ``os.path.join`` and let python do the work of properly generating the OS specific path string for you. ``r''`` is meant to make writing regex templates easier, **not** windows paths.

Comment: Also, that's not how ``args`` is meant to work in subprocess. You should not pass it one giant string that contains all of the parameters. You should pass it a list of argument strings, where each element in the list is a value you'd normally enter separated by a space (EX ``['command','--foo','bar']`` for ``$ command --foo bar``). The docs specifically states that doing otherwise can have strange behavior on windows.

Comment: On Windows you could pass the command as a string: `subprocess.check_call(r'c:\UK\app\Debug\lll.exe -unemp Base -rate Base -scen_name Base -print_progress 0 -rate_date 1 -hpa Base -dealpath C:\data\ -nthread 4 -deallist C:\config\all.txt -outdir  c:\outdir\Base')` If it works and you need to create the command dynamically and/or for portability then you could convert it to a list e.g., `check_call([r'c:\UK\app\Debug\lll.exe', '-unemp', 'Base', ...])` (each argument should be a separate list item). btw, I don't see `csv` in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe subprocess is not able to locate the file/directory..Are you sure the file is present and the path to the file does not contain any special character (e.g. ~/) ?

Otherwise try using argument `shell=True`

from the subprocess [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```